# get tabs from all documents in templates DocuSign

Tags: node.js, typescript, docusignapi

Docusign Provides a way to get tabs data for a single document in a template by specifying documentId. I could not find a way to get tabs data for all documents included in a template.

Answer (score 0):

There's no data in templates, templates are not sent, or acted upon.
Only envelopes have data, and you mentioned you can get data from envelopes.

Now, maybe you meant how can I aggregate ALL the DATA from ALL envelopes created from a template.

If that's what you meant, then you may have to first find all these envelopes.
To do this, include some meta-data in your envelopes using custom fields. These will be used to later find them first, so that then you can get all the data from them using the search envelope endpoint (that can also return data).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to see which tabs are placed on a template, you can do so by making a [Templates::Get](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templates/get/) call with `?include=recipients,tabs`.

As Inbar states, this won't get you any tab values (except one that are pre-populated by the template creator), as the template itself isn't what a signer interacts with - an envelope is sent that references the template. So if you're trying to collect data from your signers, you would need to be pulling tab data from an envelope instead.